# Synapse Analytics query fails when arguments for WHERE-IN operator contains colon like ('asdf:asdf')

Tags: t-sql, escaping, special-characters, azure-synapse, openrowset

I am using Synapse Analytics to query a simple .csv file containing a single column.
Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT a.[Product Code]
    FROM OPENROWSET(
         BULK ('https://<mystorage>.dfs.core.windows.net/<somefolder>/<filename>.csv'),
                  FORMAT = 'CSV',
                  PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
                  HEADER_ROW = TRUE
              ) as a 
    WHERE a.[Product Code] NOT IN ('123:123', '234:234234')
```

This query is quite straightforward, so I'm not sure what could go wrong.
However, I encountered an error while executing it:

```
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

After some investigation, I discovered that the issue is caused by the colon symbol (':') in the parameters.

I attempted to resolve the error by casting the parameter to VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, but this didn't help.

I also couldn't find any ways to escape the colon symbol.

Consequently, I resorted to replacing the colon with a different symbol, like this:

```
SELECT a.[Product Code]
    FROM OPENROWSET(
         BULK ('https://<mystorage>.dfs.core.windows.net/<somefolder>/<filename>.csv'),
                  FORMAT = 'CSV',
                  PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
                  HEADER_ROW = TRUE
              ) as a 
WHERE REPLACE(a.[Product Code],':',';') NOT IN ('481154559;asdfa')
```

Folks, do you have any suggestions for a better approach to handle this issue?

Comment: Does the `Product Code` field has data with `colon(:)`?

Comment: yep.. it contain data with colon

Comment: `SELECT
     *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://****.dfs.core.windows.net/***/***.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        HEADER_ROW =TRUE
    ) 
    with 
    ([Product Code] NVARCHAR(100))
    AS [result]
    where [Product Code] NOT IN ('123:123', '234:234234')`

Comment: define the schema `[product code] field as nvarchar` . Refer the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually specify the type of  [Product Code] as nvarchar(100). Refer the below code.

**Code**

```sql
SELECT
*
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://***.dfs.core.windows.net/***/***.csv',
FORMAT = 'CSV',
PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
HEADER_ROW =TRUE
)
with
(
 [Product Code] nvarchar(100)
)
AS [result]
where [Product Code] NOT  IN ('123:123', '234:234234')
```